# configuring dns to point to my hosted machine

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I want to check if I've configured things correctly. I've registered a domain at godaddy.com and created a virtual linux server at hostvirtual.com. In the godaddy dns manager interface I've added the nameservers ns1.hostvirtual.com and ns2.hostvirtual.com. At hostvirtual.com they have a dns zone editor where I've added an A record that maps the hostname of the virtual machine to its ip address. Is this right? Or do I have to add the mapping in the zone editor at godaddy.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You point your virtualhosting name server from godady.That means you should use virtualhosting name servers' interface to create your dns records. Some domain registrar are also provides name server (such as name cheap) and you don't need to point any external nameserver but just use their servers to create dns records.

Shortly what you did was right, you need to keep your dns records at your hosting company's site.

Answer (score 0):

As I believe it now stands, you have two sets, so you need to update both places.

If you just added the NS from hostvirtual without removing the GoDaddy ones you will need to change GoDaddy as well.  If you removed the GoDaddy name servers, the entries there would be irrelevant.  Alternatively, you could have left just the name servers at GoDaddy and added an A record through their interface.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. Can you elaborate exactly what problem you are facing in above setup so that we can respond accordingly.